# Actively tracking oracle query performance

Tags: performance, oracle, oracle10g, query-optimization

**Background:**

We have a database environment where views are calling views which are calling views... the logic has become complex and now changes to underlying views can have significant impact on the top view being called by the client application.

Now while we are documenting all the logic and figuring out how to unwind everything development continues on and performance continues to degrade.

Currently I would manually run an explain plan on a client query and dig into tuning it. This is a slow and tedious process and changes may not be examined for ages.

**Problem:**

I want to generate a report that lists SQL ID and lists changes in actual time/discrepancy between estimated rows and actual rows/changes in buffers/changes in reads in comparison to the average computed over the last month.

I would generally run the following script manually and examine it based just on that day's response.

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET statistics_level=all;
set linesize 256;
set pagesize 0;
set serveroutput off;

-- QUERY

SELECT
    *
FROM
    table (DBMS_XPLAN.display_cursor (NULL, NULL, 'ALLSTATS LAST'));
```

What I am trying to do is see about automating the explain plan query and inserting the statistics into a table. From there I can run a regression report to detect changes in the performance which can then alert the developers.

I was thinking something like this would be common enough without having to resorting to the OEM. I can't find anything so I wonder if there is a more common approach to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle provides functionality for this with the Automatic Workload Repositiory. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/autostat.htm

It's an extra license on top of Enterprise Edition though, I believe. It ought to be usable in non-production environments without additional cost, but check with your Oracle sales rep.

Comment: IANAL but I would be quite surprized if Oracle permitted the unlicensed use of AWR in non-prod environments, given that they require licenses for everything else in those environments.

Comment: Development licenses can be had for nothing under some circumstances, but frankly Oracle have their user community by the wotsits anyway -- the effective cost of AWR if you're using Standard Edition can be £100k+ because of the need to license EE as well.

Comment: Excellent, I'll check if we have the license - exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are on the road to re-inventing STATSPACK.  Oracle still include this in their database but don't document it any more, presumably because it's free, unlike AWR and ASH.  You can still find the documentation in [the 9i manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/statspac.htm).

Comment: Cheers! If we don't have AWR, this has saved me a load of time. Looks to contain all the functionality I want - baseline templates/sql hash reports etc. Better approach to compare against the baseline rather than a moving average.

Answer (score 0):

Active Session History (ASH) is what you are looking for

```
select * from v$active_session_history where sql_id = :yoursqlid
```

Comment: ASH is part of the DIagnostics pack, and like AWR requires an additional license on top of the Enterprise Edition license.